# ModelBinding a single parameter within an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Due to some refection-fu I want to use the MVC ModelBinders to bind the request to an object with a name and Type that is only known at runtime.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult BindSomething()
{
    Type type  = typeof(Some.Type);
    string parameterName = "someParameter"; //this corresponds to a particular form input name

    var binder = Binders.GetBinder(desiredType, true);
    var x = binder.BindModel(this.ControllerContext, ???) //??? should be a ModelBindingContext. Where can I get this from 
    return View(x);
}
```

I think I need to get hold of the ModelBindingContext, or create a new, valid one, but how do I do this?

edit: apologies if I wasn't clear enough - I already know about TryUpdateModel, but, as far as I understand it that binds ALL the posted values to properties of the model object you pass in. I just want to get the corresponding object for a single posted parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TryUpdateModel as rouen suggested, you could also implement a custom model binder that can bind the correct type. This approach has the advantage of letting you deal with Interfaces or Abstract models and keeps your binding code out of your actions. It's a little neater but I would only really recommend it if it's going to be reused in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use controller method **TryUpdateModel**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx

It will choose appropriate binder according argument type and perform model binding for you.